# I want make app to split the bill between friends

Tags: swift, calculator, fatal-error

I want to make a calculator with few screens, on the first screen "how many people we have", the second "bill", then on the third screen "result of division bill to amount of people", but it gives me a fatal error in Xcode at the end in:

```
@IBAction func equal(_ sender: Any)
...
secondInput = Double(adam.text!)! 
...
```

Code:

```
var plusAndMinus = 0
class ViewController234: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var adam: UILabel!

    @IBAction func plus(_ sender: Any) {
        plusAndMinus += 1
         adam.text = "\(plusAndMinus)"
      }
      @IBAction func minus(_ sender: Any) {
          if(plusAndMinus != 0 ) {
              plusAndMinus -= 1
          }
         adam.text = "\(plusAndMinus)"
      }
//Next Screen => Total Amount

    var first = 0.0                  //Display LABEL
    // second input = adam
    var function = ""
    var result = 0.0
    var userInput = ""



    @IBOutlet weak var Display: UILabel!

    @IBAction func numberOne(_ sender: Any) {

        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "1"
        Display.text! += userInput
    }

    @IBAction func numberTwo(_ sender: Any) {

        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "2"
        Display.text! += userInput

    }

    @IBAction func numberThree(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "3"
        Display.text! += userInput
        }

    @IBAction func numberFour(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "4"
        Display.text! += userInput
        }

    @IBAction func numberFive(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "5"
        Display.text! += userInput
    }

    @IBAction func numberSix(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "6"
        Display.text! += userInput
    }

    @IBAction func numberSeven(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "7"
        Display.text! += userInput
    }

    @IBAction func numberEight(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "8"
        Display.text! += userInput
    }

    @IBAction func numberNine(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "9"
        Display.text! += userInput
    }

    @IBAction func numberZero(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += "0"
        Display.text! += userInput
    }
    @IBAction func clear(_ sender: Any) {
        first = 0.0
        function = ""
        userInput = ""
        result = 0.0
        Display.text = ""
    }

    @IBAction func virgule(_ sender: Any) {
        Display.text = ""
        userInput += ","
        Display.text! += userInput
    }

    @IBAction func equal(_ sender: Any) {
        function = "/"
        var firstInput = 0.0
        firstInput = Double(first)
        var secondInput = 0.0
        secondInput = Double(adam.text!)!         //Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

        result = firstInput / secondInput
        lastDisplay.text = String(result)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var lastDisplay: UILabel!
```

Comment: Please edit question to include what this “Fatal error” was. What showed up on the console? At what line?

Comment: Either the outlet `Adam` is not connected, the `text` property is `nil` or the value in `adam.text` is not convertible to `Double`. Any `!` is an invitation: *Please crash me*. Handle the optionals safely. And you can reduce all `number...` IBActions to one by assigning tags to the buttons and use that as coefficient.